# Is there an equivalent of the WP Options Framework for Joomla?

Tags: joomla, frameworks, wordpress-theming, joomla-extensions

Does anybody know if there is an equivalent to the Wordpress [options framework](http://wordpress.org/plugins/options-framework/) for Joomla? I dont mean a fully fledged framework with its own grid and theme hooks etc I mean just a options panel framework to make creating template options easier and faster?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Template options are added via the XML file as they are for any Joomla extension.

Comment: Thank you, it is at least good to know